# Defining a default mapping class

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate

I've got an entity class, e.g.

```
public class Title{
   public virtual int Id { get; set; }
   public virtual string Isin { get; set; }
   public virtual string Note { get; set; }
   public virtual string Description { get; set; }
}
```

And two fluent hibernate mapping classes, each with an entity-name attribute:

```
public class ViewTitleMap:ClassMap<Title>{
    public ViewTitleMap(){
         EntityName("ViewTitle");
         Schema("consolidated");
         Table("vTitles");
         LazyLoad();
         Id(_ => _.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
         Map(_ =>     _.Description).Length(10).Nullable().CustomType("AnsiString");
         Map(_ => _.Isin).Length(12).Not.Nullable();
         Map(_ => _.Note).Length(12).Nullable();
     }
}
```

and

```
public class TitleMap:ClassMap<Title>
    {
        public TitleMap()
        {
            EntityName("title");
            Schema("dbo");
            Table("Title");
            LazyLoad();
            Id(_ => _.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity().Column("Id");
            Map(_ => _.Description).Column("Description").Length(10).Nullable();
            Map(_ => _.Isin).Length(12).Column("Isin").Not.Nullable();
            Map(_ => _.Note).Column("Note").Length(12).Nullable();
        } 
}
```

*Is it possible to define a "default" mapping (for example the mapping class with entity-name "title"), so when i query I don't need to write the entity name I want to use (and viceversa, putting the entity-name only when necessary)?*

E.g. (with premise of mapping class with entity-name "title" as default mapping) I don't want to write every time this

```
Title title = session.QueryOver<Title>("title").Where(_ =>_.Id == titleId).SingleOrDefault();
```

but only

```
Title title = session.QueryOver<Title>.Where(_ =>_.Id == titleId).SingleOrDefault();
```

While I want to use this

```
Title title = session.QueryOver<Title>("ViewTitle").Where(_ =>_.Id == titleId).SingleOrDefault();
```

only in particular situations. This is because the prominent use of the "title" entity-map against "ViewTitle"

Thank you